# where is pugjs Includes api source code?

Tags: pug

Visit [pugjs includes](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html)

Visit [pugjs github](https://github.com/pugjs/)

---

1. i can not found "include" api source code. pugjs team don't open
   source?
2. i have search this question from google, but can't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are searching the source-code of the `input` functionality within pug.

Try [searching through the repo](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/search?l=JavaScript&q=include&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93). Specifically, look at `packages/pug-load/index.js`.

The PugJS project is fully open source.